# Angular http.post => Cloud Function : Reading Data from POST

Tags: angular, firebase, http, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to do a simple POST request to a Google Cloud Function from Angular (using `@angular/common/http`) but the Angular http docs for v7 barely provide any thorough examples, nothing listed for how to attach data or an object to the request.

My Angular code:

```
    const url = 'example.com/this/that';

    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        })
    };

    const data = {
        "id": id, 
        "name": name
    }

    return this.http.post(url, data, httpOptions)
        .subscribe(res => {
            console.log(res);
        });
```

And my Google Cloud Function:

```
export const myFunction= functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    return cors(request, response, () => {

        const id = request.query.id;
        const name = request.query.name;

        console.log('> > > > > > > 1.1 < < < < < < <');
        console.log(request);

        if (!name || !id) {
            return response.status(400).send(`Missing parameters`);
        }

        return response.status(200).send(`Thank you for id ${id} and name ${name}.`);

    });
});
```

<s>I always get 400, "Missing parameters". I've also tried `request.body.id`. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!</s>

**EDIT**:

Misread the error in client console, `req.body` was indeed working. I was getting a parsing error. Adding error picture

Also, I've posted a solution as an answer to this question. Thanks to Doug for his help too, `req.query` was indeed wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is ***not to send a string*** in `res.status(200).sent('some string here');` but to ***send an object***:

(in the Google Cloud Function *response*):

```
res.status(200).send({status: 200, message: `Thank you for id ${id}`});
```

Answer (score 2):

With Express [Request](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req) objects, [`request.query`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query) refers to the parameters coming in through the query string directly in the URL.  You're not passing anything that way, so you'll end up with an empty object.

Cloud Functions should [automatically parse the request body](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#parsing_http_requests) formatted as JSON, and put the results in `request.body`, so use that instead to access your id and name.

Comment: Thanks for your response, @Doug. I think the function is working correctly with `.body` but I get this weird error. I think I need to `JSON.parse()` either in the cloud or locally. I put the error image in my original question if you want to have a look.